# Comparing and printing elements in nested loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

The program identifies if one of the elements in the string `word` is a consonant by looping though the `word` string, and then for each iteration though the `word` string, iterating though the `consonants` list and comparing if the current element in `word` string equals to the current element of `consonant` list.

If yes, the current element of the `word` string is a consonant and the consonant gets printed (not the index of the consonant, but the actual consonant, for e.g. "d".)

The problem is, I get this instead:

```
1
1
```

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the nested loops work so that the below loop iterates every element for each element in the above loop? That is, each index above makes the below loop iterate though each index?

That's the program:

```
word = "Hello"

consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z']

for character in range(len(word)): 
    for char in range(len(consonants)): 
        if consonants[char] == word[character]: 
            consonant = word[character]
            print consonant
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are *misreading* the output. The character is the **letter L** lowercase, not the number 1.

In other words, your code is working as designed. The captital letter `H` is not in your `consonants` list, but the two lowercase letters `l` in `Hello` *are*.

Note that it'd be much more efficient to use a `set` for `consonants` here; you'd not have to loop over that whole list and just use `in` to test for membership. That works with lists too, but is much more efficient with a set. If you lowercase the `word` value you'd also be able to match the `H`.

Last but not least, you can loop over the `word` string *directly* rather than use `range(len(word))` then use the generated index:

```
word = "Hello"
consonants = set('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz')

for character in word.lower():
    if character in consonants:
        print character
```

Demo:

```
>>> word = "Hello"
>>> consonants = set('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz')
>>> for character in word.lower():
...     if character in consonants:
...         print character
... 
h
l
l
```

Comment: Wow, didn't realize 'H' is different from lowercase 'h'. This is funny.

Comment: So the `in` statement can also be used with lists in the same way? Thank you for this! :)